# How can I force rdocumentation.org to update to latest version?

Tags: r, documentation

How can I force rdocumentation.org to update its documentation to the latest version on a github library?

In my case, the library is `lares`, and it is hosted in [Github](https://github.com/laresbernardo/lares). It is already indexed by rdocumentation.org but the it is showing as the latest version a very old version.

In [this link](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/lares) you can check the documentation showed, and the latest version is `v4.7` (not `v4.4`).

Comment: It will but I found that it is a bit on and off. Today it will show one version, the next day something else.

Comment: I don't think this is a programming question, so it seems off-topic here. Rdocumentation is owned by Data Camp, so you might try [contacting them](https://support.datacamp.com/hc/en-us/articles/360021185634-How-To-Contact-DataCamp).